# Android add a button to a Fragment

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I am trying to add buttons to a Fragment.  Basically I get a null pointer exception when I try the button.  Without the button code the fragment works fine.  In past posts I saw that view.findViewById was used but that will not function here.  All of the other answers which I have tries also failed.  What do y'all thin that I am doing wrong?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    // LOG Tags
    public static String DATABASE = "Database";

    Boolean userexists = false;
    Button btnNewDocument;


    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        btnNewDocument = (Button) btnNewDocument.findViewById(R.id.btnNewDocument);
        btnNewDocument.setEnabled(false);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
btnNewDocument = (Button) btnNewDocument.findViewById(R.id.btnNewDocument);
```

use:

```
btnNewDocument = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNewDocument);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but why does rootView work?  What is it?

Comment: reference to the xml layout file. If you remember in Activity we use `this`.

Comment: Because your button is being inflated by fragment so findviewbyid have to be called from fragment's reference. Additionally you can use getview() instead of rootview.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
btnNewDocument = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNewDocument);
```

If you still get a Null Pointer Exception you should check if fragment_home contains a button element with id "btnNewDocument"